# How to fill a vector bit by bit

Tags: vhdl

I have a 12 bits vector called **RDIBits** and a in std_logic called **InUartToUart**. My question is: every time the clock goes to '1', i receive a bit in **InUartToUart**, and i want to concat all the 12 bits that i will receive in the **RDIBits** vector. Basically, its a serial communication, thats why i receive 1 bit each time. Is there any simple way to do this? Something similar to **RDIBits += InUartToUart** in JAVA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would code this slightly differently.  Maybe consider this.
Sorry about the formatting, Im new to this site.  I have also shown how you can initialise the variable.

```
signal RDIBits : std_logic_vector(11 downto 0) := (Others => '0');

...
process(clk)
begin
    if ( rising_edge(clk) ) then
        RDIBits(11 downto 1) <= RDIBits(10 downto 0);
        RDIBits(0) <= InUartToUart;
    end if;
end process;
```

Answer (score 1):

I added some more things, like the entity, the IOs and a counter for the output register.

```
LIBRARY ieee;
    USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    USE ieee.numeric_std.all;


ENTITY my_uart IS
    PORT(
        clk                    : IN  std_logic;                     -- system clock
        rst                    : IN  std_logic;                     -- reset high active
        ---------------------------------------------
        InUartToUart           : IN  std_logic;
        DataOut                : OUT std_logic_vector(11 downto 0)
   );
END ENTITY;

ARCHITECTURE struct OF my_uart IS
signal RDIBits : std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
signal counter : integer range 0 to 12;

begin

    calc_proc: process(clk, rst)
    begin
        if (rst = '1') then
            RDIBits <= (others => '0');
            counter <= 0;
        elsif ( rising_edge(clk) ) then
            if (counter < 12) then
                RDIBits <= RDIBits(10 downto 0) & InUartToUart;
                counter <= counter + 1;
            elsif (counter = 12) then
                DataOut <= RDIBits;
                counter <= 0;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

END STRUCT;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical shift register application.  For example:

```
signal RDIBits : std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);

...

process(clk)
begin
  if ( rising_edge(clk) ) then
    RDIBits <= RDIBits(10 downto 0) & InUartToUart;
  end if;
end process;
```